# Connecting a Spring Boot Application with a Dockerized MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, docker, spring-boot

First, I have dockerized a datasource, and I have linked it to a network.

1. Follow the guideline just here : https://github.com/SimonGirardSfeir/MySQL-Docker
2. Create a network
   docker network create -d bridge mybridge
3. Link the image of the database to the network
   docker run -d --net=mybridge --name=db docker-mysql
4. I go to the database in the shell to add the appropriate properties (username, password, name of the database), it works ok.

Now, it is perfectly ok.

Now, I am trying to link a Spring boot application with the following properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://db:3306/db_example
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword

# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1
```

And the Dockerfile is the following :

```
# Start with a base image containing Java runtime
FROM java:8-jre

# Add a volume pointing to /tmp
VOLUME /tmp

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# The application's jar file
ARG JAR_FILE=build/libs/mysql-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

# Add the application's jar to the container
ADD ${JAR_FILE} mysql.jar


RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install mysql-client -y
RUN apt-get install libmysql-java -y

# Run the jar file
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/mysql.jar"]
```

1. I build from the Dockerfile, it is ok.
2. Hence, I launch the following command
   docker run --net=mybridge --name=app myappimage

But, the program is unable to connect to the database and the logs show:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   Communications link failure

I don't understand where is the problem.

My sources are :
https://docs.docker.com/v17.03/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/#add-containers-to-a-network
https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25562

Comment: Are you able to connect to the dockerised DB when running the application locally(not on docker)?

Comment: Yes, totally, and the applications properties files, is like this :
https://github.com/SimonGirardSfeir/SpringBoot-MySQL-Docker/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.properties
I map the port 3360, to the 6603 of localhost

Comment: After running both the dockerised db and app linked to the network,  run this command: `docker network inspect mybridge` and check if the `Containers` section contains both your instances.

Comment: It contain the database instance, for sure. If I run the java app, it contains it too (only few seconds) but the connection exception stops it.

Comment: Try this:
1. Comment out the db connection code from the app, so the app doesn't stop.
2. Run both the db and the app on the same network (as you have been doing).
3. `exec` into the app container and do a `curl` to your db url (just `<host>:<port>`) and see if you get a 200. This way, you can verify if you are able to connect to the db with the url that you are using.

Comment: That s ok, I think the problem comes from the application.properties file. The datasource seems to be unknown....